# match comma separated values in same column

Tags: r

lets say i have the following dataframe:: this is one column of a bigger dataset I have but that is not relevent at the time.

```
             first_column
1 hallo, test, twee, dire
2    hi, vier, twee, vijf
3   biep, boep, yes, twee
```

what I want to do is find matching values in the column:: so this example would give an output of::

```
twee
```

But I do not have an answer to how to approach this, first I thought `match()` would do the trick but that is not working.

Comment: So you want values that are present in every row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` with `intersect`:

```r
Reduce(intersect, strsplit(df$first_column, ", "))
#[1] twee
```